# Как получить id существующей записи

Tags: sql-server

Как получить  id существующей записи, а если записи нет, то вставить новую?
Сейчас использую три запроса:

```
If exists (select id from tab where place=@place)
Select @id=id from tab where place=@place
Else
Begin
Insert into tab ...
Set @id=@@identity
End
```

Есть варианты получше?

Comment: что-то у вас язык  не тот. В самом первом запросе нельзя что ли сразу выбрать @id, а потом проверить его на null ? будет два запроса

Comment: Так если там пусто он не вернет null

Comment: Текст "в три запроса" утверждает. что поле `place` - уникальное. Если так - то можно безусловно выполнить вставку (если будет ошибка - игнорировать), а потом выборку значения `id`. Также можно использовать MERGE (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625(v=sql.105).aspx) и получить `id` через OUTPUT.

Answer (score 2):

Особо красивого способа к сожалению нет. Можно, например, сделать только одно обращение с проверкой наличия записи:

```
Select @id=id from tab where place=@place
If @@rowcount = 0 begin
  Insert into tab ...
  Set @id=scope_identity()
End
```

Можно ал-ля одним запросом, но оно громоздко выходит:

```
declare @ids table (id int)

merge Tab D
 using (values('xxx')) S(place) on D.place=S.place
when not matched then
 insert (place) values(S.place)
when matched then
 update set place=place
output inserted.id into @ids
;
-- На выходе получили переменную табличного типа, если вдруг надо, 
-- переписываем в переменную числового типа
declare @id int
select @id=id from @ids
```

Comment: Во втором варианте `update set id=id` - c _identity_ такое не прокатит.

Comment: @i-one Спасибо, поправил

Comment: В первом варианте тоже есть нюансы (даже если принять отсутствие concurrency). Напр. если это кусок кода откуда-то, и переменная `@id` реюзается. Если в `@id` перед запросом что-то лежало (не _NULL_), а значения с таким `@place` не нашлось, тогда в тело _if_ не попадём. Лучше проверить `@@rowcount = 0`, плюс `@@identity` лучше заменить на `scope_identity()`.

Comment: `update set place=place` безобиден лишь семантически, он нагрузит дополнительно журнал транзакций. В общем я за первый вариант (если нет параллельных транзакций).

Comment: @i-one Ну да, а без этого дурацкого update в inserted ничего нет :(

Comment: Можно ещё `update set @id=id` (это не нагрузит лог, если запись уже есть), но в сочетании с `output into @ids` это какое-то масло масленое.